# How can I dynamically import a directory of files from within a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to import files from a directory from within a loop to dynamically generate routes. As you can see in my (Working from index file (my initial code), I attempted to use (import.meta.url) because I wanted this to be a sync operation. The error I got was as follow:

First Error:

> [ERROR] 11:51:22 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
> src/routes/index.ts(26,33): error TS1343: The 'import.meta'
> meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020',
> 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node12', or 'nodenext'.

***This is what I tried.***

After Google searches I tried the code in the (One of the things I tried) section below. I ran into this error which is strange to me since I am actually using the dynamic import.

> [ERROR] 11:52:20 Error: require() of ES Module
> /app/src/routes/module-streams.js from /app/src/routes/index.ts not
> supported. Instead change the require of module-streams.js in
> /app/src/routes/index.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in
> all CommonJS modules.

Honestly even if I got the second approach I tried working, I am not thrilled about having to deal with promises. I want to import the function of each of the many routes, invoke it and create the routes during startup. This is a mock server and I am attempting to reduce the boilerplate code for adding new JSON. The funny thing is I was able to get my first approach working in another place in the app importing JSON. The code is almost identical and I get no complaint.

Really all I want to do is dynamically get the files and invoke the functions synchronously if possible. I never imaged this would be so problematic. It certainly was not with require.

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "mock-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/server.ts",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8"
  }
}
```

***tsconfig***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
  }
}
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --only=prod

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

***One of the route files i am attepting to import***

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ModuleStreams = mongoose.model('ModuleStreams', new mongoose.Schema({
  moduleName: String,
  streamName: String,
  status: String,
  softwareSourceId: String,
  profiles: Array
}, { collection : 'module-streams' }));

export default (services) => {
  let router = express.Router();

  router.route('/')
    .get((req, res, next) => {
      ModuleStreams.find({}, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);

        res.send(data);
      });
    });

  return router;
};
```

***Working from index file (my initial code)***

```
import fs from 'fs';

import { createRequire } from "module";

export const routes = () => {
  const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
  const dir = process.cwd() + '/src/routes';

  const paths = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
    .map(item => item.name);

  paths.forEach(filePath => {
    const fileNameSegments = filePath.split('.');
    const routeName = fileNameSegments[0];

    if (routeName !== 'index') {
      const content = require(`./${filePath}`);

      const test = import(`./${filePath}`);
    }
  });
};
```

***One of the things I tried***

```
import fs from 'fs';

export const routes = () => {
  const dir = process.cwd() + '/src/routes';

  const paths = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
    .map(item => item.name);

  paths.forEach(filePath => {
    const fileNameSegments = filePath.split('.');
    const routeName = fileNameSegments[0];

    if (routeName !== 'index') {
      const test = import(`./${filePath}`);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Is there are a reason why you don't want to change your transpilation options (ES5 target and CommonJS modules) like the error messages suggest?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the first error, I wasn't sure what to change it to. I tried changing the module option in the tsconfig to other types and it didn't work. Can you be more specific with the change you think I should make. It seems like your suggesting to change two values, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your project running with **import-sync**, a library I wrote in 2023:

- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-sync
- github: https://github.com/nktnet1/import-sync

as well as using `async`/`await` with the built-in [dynamic import()](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions) that ships with NodeJS.

I will assume, from the error messages in your question, that your project is set up like this:

```
mock-server
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── example.ts
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── server.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

---

## 1. Synchronous Approach: import-sync

**import-sync** wraps around [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) and will enable you to dynamically import ESM/CJS modules into your ESM/CJS-based projects at runtime (any combination of ESM/CJS will work).

Here are the steps:

1. Install [import-sync](https://github.com/nktnet1/import-sync)
2. Update [ts-node-dev](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev) to the latest version (2.0.0 as of writing)

   ```bash
   npm install --save-dev ts-node-dev@latest
   ```
3. Remove `"type": "module"` from `package.json` (there are other ways to remove the ts-node-dev exception "Error: Must use import to load ES Module", but this is the simplest with the way your project is set up), giving

   ```json
   {
     "name": "mock-server",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "server.js",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "ts-node-dev src/server.ts",
       "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"
     },
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "dependencies": {
       "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
       "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
       "express": "^4.17.3",
       "import-sync": "^2.1.2",
       "mongoose": "^6.3.0",
       "typescript": "^4.6.3"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0"
     }
   }
   ```
4. Use the `importSync` function in your `src/routes/index.ts`:

   ```js
   import fs from 'fs';
   import importSync from 'import-sync';

   export const routes = async () => {
     const dir = process.cwd() + '/src/routes';

     const paths = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
       .filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
       .map(item => item.name);

     paths.forEach(filePath => {
       const fileNameSegments = filePath.split('.');
       const routeName = fileNameSegments[0];

       if (routeName !== 'index') {
         const test = importSync(`./${filePath}`);
         console.log('Imported module is:', test);
       }
     });
   };
   ```

Here is the result:

[image: Results using import-sync]

Now, of course, that's if you want to use synchronous code like in your original example.

---

## 2. Async/Await: dynamic import()

It is also possible to convert the `routes` export in `src/routes/index.ts` to `async`, then simply `await` the [dynamic import()](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions). This means you'll no longer need [import-sync](https://github.com/nktnet1/import-sync).

The steps are almost the same as before:

1. Uninstall [import-sync](https://github.com/nktnet1/import-sync) if you installed it in the previous step
2. Same as before, ensure that [ts-node-dev](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev) is of version 2.0.0
3. Same as before, ensure that you **don't** have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`
4. In your `src/routes/index.ts`, you need to:

   1. Change the `routes` function to be `async`
   2. Change `paths.forEach(filePath => ...)` to `for (const filePath of paths)` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) for why we need to
   3. Add `await import(...)` in place of `importSync(...)`

   The resulting code should look like this:

   ```js
   import fs from 'fs';

   export const routes = async () => {
     const dir = process.cwd() + '/src/routes';

     const paths = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
       .filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
       .map(item => item.name);

     for (const filePath of paths) {
       const fileNameSegments = filePath.split('.');
       const routeName = fileNameSegments[0];

       if (routeName !== 'index') {
         const test = await import(`./${filePath}`);
         console.log('Using async/await:', test);
       }
     }
   };
   ```

Which will give us:

[image: Async/await usage]

Hope this helps :)